# Convert IEnumerable in List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I am creating a control that receive in datasource a DataSet or List

How i convert a IEnumerable to List in a CreateChildControls event?

```
protected override int CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
{
    if (dataSource is System.Data.DataSet)
    {
    }
    else if(dataSource is IList)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually one would use the `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()` extensionmethod from Linq but in your case you can not use it (right away) because you have the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface. Sou you will have to cast it first (also using Linq):

```
datasource.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

No matter what you original collection actually ist, this will always succeed.

Comment: thanks, how i can get the original Type and not set a object type?

Comment: In case that type is always the same it is as simple as `datasource.Cast<MySpecificType>().ToList();` In case it is not, you have a design issue. One solution would be to give all your item types in your collection a generic interface that contains all members you need in your consumer method `CreateChildControls()`, e.g. `datasource.Cast<IDataInfo>().ToList();`

Comment: @bitbonk: If your code falls through the `datasource is IList` then it will be a list. No need to create a list, you can just cast to a list. Then the issue of 'original format' is not a problem

Comment: @TechTestDude You are right. But I would argue for the sake of maintainablitly and readablity those type checks should probably go away. Premature performance optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I agree, converting back isnt simply for performance tho, it enhances your information retention (as opposed to having a list of object, you have the original list back.

Answer (score 6):

I re-read your question and it seems that you are receiving a dataset which is ALREADY a list OR a DataSet, but it is cast to an IEnumerable. In this case, simply do

```
IList myList = (IList)datasource //will throw exception if invalid
```

or

```
IList myList = datasource as IList //mylist will be null if conversion cannot be made
```

Comment: `dataSource.ToList()` won't work because dataSource is not of type IEnumerable<T>

Comment: This is true, i edited it to reflect such. There is no need to create a new list because if the 'x is y' test suceeeds then a simple (y)x will yeild your result with little processing overhead

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question 'how i can get the original Type and not set a object type?'.

Every type in .NET framework contains `GetType` method to fetch the type of the specified object.  You can use it before `ToList` method.